# Split String in R for several signs

Tags: r, string

How can I split a string like

```
x = "0.989(0.975)&0.964(0.937)&0.877(0.771)&&0.962(0.903)&0.971(0.867)&0.932(0.828)&&0.984(0.892)&0.937(0.869)&0.910(0.722)&&0.970(0.867)&0.942(0.811)&0.875(0.747)"
```

to get all numbers is a numeric vector like

```
y = c(0.989, 0.975, 0.964, 0.937, 0.877)
```

and so on.

I want to eliminate the parentheses, the "&" and "&&".

Answer (score 4):

Use `gsub` with `scan` i.e. `gsub` to replace all the characters other than the `.` and digits with a single delimiter `,` and then with `scan` read it at once

```
out <- scan(text = gsub("[^.0-9]+", ",", x), what = numeric(), 
    sep=",", quiet = TRUE)

str(out)
#num [1:25] 0.989 0.975 0.964 0.937 0.877 0.771 0.962 0.903 0.971 0.867 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `regmatches` + `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+\\.\\d+", x))[[1]])
```

gives

```
 [1] 0.989 0.975 0.964 0.937 0.877 0.771 0.962 0.903 0.971 0.867 0.932 0.828
[13] 0.984 0.892 0.937 0.869 0.910 0.722 0.970 0.867 0.942 0.811 0.875 0.747
```